# What was the cause of some egg-laying animals evolution to animal-laying?

Tags: evolution, cell-biology, zoology

Is there a specific reason for this evolution? Are no egg-laying animals more complex beings so their embryonic  development requires more time and better nutrition conditions?

Comment: Oviparity to viviparity (and vice versa and middle ground with ovoviparity) has evolved a number of times. Is there a specific lineage you have in mind when asking this question?

Comment: [Wikipedia > viviparity#evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviparity#Evolution) will probably give some useful information

Comment: No I think that first appeared oviparity an then viviparity.